# Is there any possiblility to login to our app from device settings like what facebook app does in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, settings

I need a confirmation that is it possible to login to my own app by giving the credentials in the settings of the device.

flow is like:
settings -> tap onto my app -> enter username, password and version -> tap home button ->tap on my app -> then it should show the homescreen instead login screen.

For ex: The Facebook app works same as we can enter the credentials and signedin in the device settings and when we trap on to the facebook app it automatically sign in.

I need confirmation whether its possible or not

Comment: No, this is not possible For more chk https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: It's possible, but not a good idea, the user won't expect to have the login on the settings app

Comment: @jcesar: Can u guide me how is it possible. Actually its a client requirement So I have to go for it,

Comment: The only thing possible is that you can store userName and password in setting for your app and when user open the app, it will check fro credentials filled in setting and try to login based on it

Comment: In the link Aman provided you have more info about the fields you can use in the settings, use Text fields for the password and user, password with is secure attribute.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal, if you read his question, that's what he wants

Comment: @jcesar i thought he just wants to signin in settings app, like facebook does. That's why i wrote its not possible

Comment: @jcesar: Wt aman told is exactly right.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal: I need wt exactly facebook app does for sign in in settings.

Comment: To be clear. Facebook app sign in with the iOS system in the settings app, so you can share things on facebook from anywhere. This isn't possible on your app. What it's possible is the user fill the username and password on the settings app, and then your app read this values and uses them to sign in automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey monish kumar may this URL help you
http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118144252.html
this URL link to book in which chapter 9 explain you how to achieve it and also provide you code also

Comment: @kamelesh kumar yadav: Yes it works for me... This is what I need... tanq.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not a good idea.

However here are the implementation steps..

Implement an [iOS Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) with two text feilds such as user name and password.

In AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` , retreive this details and do it whatever you need.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

 NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *userName = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"userName"];

 NSUserDefaults * pswd = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *userName = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"password"];

 if (userName == expectedUsername && pswd == expectedPswd) {

    //load the home screen
 }
 else
 {
    //load the login screen
 }
}
```

To implement a settings bundle, please [read this link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html)

Comment: In any way, if you're going to implement it like this, you should think twice. There is zero encryption on these sensitive things, if you like your users, you should dig a little deeper. Keychain for iCloud might be a good start...